# How can I get untrusted device for enterprise (in-house) iOS app?

Tags: ios, mdm, software-distribution, in-house-distribution

I'm distributing an **iOS In-House application**. But I want to get untrusted device list. How can I identify **untrusted certificate authority** particular device until the app is installed on the device?

For exmple :- User press the **Don't Trust** button as per below image. I want to know if some user does not trust my App this way.

[image]

I have explored in web but haven't found anything helpful.
Is it feasible? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to collect data of users refusing to let your app run. Think of it this way, your sole connection to the user is your app. Before the App is launched, the user refuses to let it run. How do you suppose you could collect data of a user who refused your app to run from an app that hasn't been launched and won't be launched at all?

Comment: It is highly recommended that you distribute enterprise apps via an MDM solution; this way the user isn't prompted to trust the developer.  Trust is established automatically